# How to plot values from dictionary from highest to next lowest depending on user input

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, plot

I have specific values in a dictionary that sort from high to low however there can be up to a thousand or more values. How can it take a user input if a number between say 1-10 and give the output of a graph with the top 1-10 highest values in the dict. So if they input a 3 it will graph the 3 highest values etc.

```
from collections import Counter
from scipy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot


frequency1 = Counter({'1':100,'2':400,'3':200,'4':300,})



response1 = input("How many top domains from source? Enter a number between 1-10: ")

if response1 == "1":        
    if len(frequency1) >= 1:

        print("\nTop 1 most is:")
        for key, frequency1_value in frequency1.most_common(1):
                print("\nNumber:",key,"with frequency:",frequency1_value)
                
                ########Graph for this output  
        
                x = [1,2]
                y = [frequency1_value,0]

                figure(1)
        
                ax = plot.subplot(111)
                ax.bar(x,y,align='center', width=0.2, color = 'm')
        
            
                ax.set_xticklabels(['0', '1'])
                xlabel("This graph shows amount of protocols used")
                ylabel("Number of times used")
                grid('on')      

        
################################## END GRAPH 
    else: 
        print("\nThere are not enough domains for this top amount.")
    
if response1 == "2":        
    if len(frequency1) >= 2: 
        print("\nTop 2 most is:")
        for key, frequency1_value in frequency1.most_common(2):
                print("\nNumber:",key,"with frequency:",frequency1_value)
                
                ########Graph for this output  
        
                x = [1,2,3]
                y = [frequency1_value,frequency1_value,0]

                figure(1)
        
                ax = plot.subplot(111)
                ax.bar(x,y,align='center', width=0.2, color = 'm')
        
            
                ax.set_xticklabels(['0', '1','','2'])
                xlabel("This graph shows amount of protocols used")
                ylabel("Number of times used")
                grid('on')      

        
################################## END GRAPH 
                
    else: 
        print("\nThere are not enough domains for this top amount.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will create a sorted list of the values in the dictionary and then plot the corresponding graph of the largest numbers, depending on the user input.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'1':100,'2':400,'3':200,'4':300,}

vals = sorted(d.values(), reverse=True)

response = input("How many top domains from source? Enter a number between 1-10: ")

if response > 0 and response < len(vals)+1:

    y = vals[:response]

    print ("\nTop %i most are:" %response)
    print (y)

    x = np.arange(1,len(y)+1,1)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.bar(x,y,align='center', width=0.2, color = 'm')

    ax.set_xticks(x)
    ax.set_xticklabels(x)
    ax.set_xlabel("This graph shows amount of protocols used")
    ax.set_ylabel("Number of times used")
    ax.grid('on')   
else:
    print ("\nThere are not enough domains for this top amount.")

plt.show()
```

For example, if the user inputted 3 into the code, the following graph would be produced with output:

```
Top 3 most are:
[400, 300, 200]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you response! Does this work with python 3.5? I get an error str() > int() on line 19.

Comment: Actually I got it, the input needed to be cast to an int.. Thanks for your help!